# executing npm install causes fsevents error

Tags: node.js, typescript, macos, npm, aws-serverless

I have created a new typescript project using serverless. When I try to install the packages I receive an fsevents error. Below is the full script from the creating of the project to installing the packages

OS: mac
npm: 6.14.4
node: 12.16.3

```
stmf@ml0195091 services % sls create -t aws-nodejs-typescript
Serverless: Generating boilerplate...
 _______                             __
|   _   .-----.----.--.--.-----.----|  .-----.-----.-----.
|   |___|  -__|   _|  |  |  -__|   _|  |  -__|__ --|__ --|
|____   |_____|__|  \___/|_____|__| |__|_____|_____|_____|
|   |   |             The Serverless Application Framework
|       |                           serverless.com, v1.70.1
 -------'

Serverless: Successfully generated boilerplate for template: "aws-nodejs-typescript"
Serverless: NOTE: Please update the "service" property in serverless.yml with your service name
stmf@ml0195091 services % npm install
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.

> fsevents@1.2.13 install /Users/stmf/Documents/development/esg/esg-data-api/services/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents
> node install.js

gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: read ECONNRESET
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.4.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/stmf/Documents/development/esg/esg-data-api/services/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN services@1.0.0 No repository field.

added 420 packages from 305 contributors in 22.939s
```

Answer (score 0):

faced similar issue, and after adding below code to package.json re-run npm install/ yarn install

```
"resolutions": {
        "**/**/node-gyp": "5.0.0"
}
```